# SIM card removed?

Tags: camera, sim-card, system-error

Apparently I'm getting this message after using the phone camera. But not all the time. Then it restarts.

What could be the problem?

Nexus 4, Android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've had this problem before. I suggest powering off, removing SIM card, then putting it back in (if possible) and reboot. Please check the card for any visual damage.